# How to run query until one record is found?

Tags: php, mysql

This is what i am trying right now but no luck

```
$bid  = $next - 2;//This subtracts 2 from the number, this number is also auto generated 

    $preid = $bid;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM  images where imageid = '$preid'";
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    while(mysqli_num_rows($sql) !=0) {
        $select_query = "SELECT * FROM  images where imageid = '$preid'";
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn,$select_query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        --$preid;
    }
```

whats suppose to happen is that if a record does not exist it subtracts 1 from preid and runs the query again with the new preid and keeps happening until a record it found but cant figure out how to do it.

Comment: $next is auto generated  number

Comment: Should be `while(mysqli_num_rows == 0)` If u wanne test for empty set. On a side note this code is vulnerable for an infinite loop

Comment: @DarkBee Good point with the infinite loop!

Comment: infinite loop, in theory, but php will time it out if configured properly, which is going to make for an unstable interface.  OP I think you need to rethink your approach.  You really don't want to do this.

Comment: This could be much more efficient if you simply grab all rows with an ID lower than your start value, order them descending, and the limit the number of rows to 1. It'll have pretty much the same output (assuming you only want one row, which seems reasonable for selecting an ID column)

Comment: @Erik its a good idea the only thing is that if a row does not exist how becuase $preid a number that is not in the database how would i subtract one and then re-run the query?

Comment: You would not have to; such a query would automatically return the first valid result. If nothing is returned, then there are no valid results with lower IDs either.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are constantly checking database for new values. However, on a large scale application thi is an highly inefficient way to constantly ping the database.
You have made a variable $preid but you are not using it anywhere.
This is how i would do it if i were to go according to your way

```
$bid  = $next - 2;//This subtracts 2 from the number, this number is also auto generated 

$preid = $bid;
$query = "SELECT * FROM  images where imageid = '$preid'";
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

while(mysqli_num_rows($sql) !=0 || !$preid) { //notice here i added the condition for preid.
    $select_query = "SELECT * FROM  images where imageid = '$preid'";
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn,$select_query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    --$preid;
}
```

now what happens is that the loop will run as long as either of the two condition stays true ie either a row is returned from the database or it will keep searching until **preid** is not 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test for an empty set, your while should run while mysqli_num_rows == 0

```
while(mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 0) {
        $select_query = "SELECT * FROM  images where imageid = '$preid'";
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn,$select_query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        $preid--; 
    }
```

As @DarkBee has mentionend in his comment, this code is highly vulnerable for an infinite loop which will take down your script, as soon as there are no entries for anything.